# How to convert data in array to string c++

Tags: c++, arrays, string

I have arrays which contains either 1 or 0. I would like to append it and become one line string. At the moment I had failed doing so. here is my code. Please help because I could not manage to complete it. Everytime I load the final result to the console, only smiley faces and not 1 or 0. Please help

```
int pixelValueArray[256];
String testing;

for(int d=0;d<256;d++)
{
    testing.append(1,pixelValueArray[d]);
}

cout<<testing;
```

Comment: The ASCII code for character "0" is 48. Instead of writing the number `48`, it's a good idea to write the more self-documenting `'0'`.

Comment: Hi, actually I wanted to use the string for my ANN in opencv. The string must be converted to this cv::Mat data(1,ATTRIBUTES,CV_32F). Is there any way that the data inside the array can be converted to the MAT data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ASCII values for integer digits are given by `'0' + digit`.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
    testing.append(1, '0' + pixelValueArray[i]);
```

Or you could use the simpler `+=`

```
for(int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
    testing += '0' + pixelValueArray[i];
```

Comment: Thanks so much ... BTW I had used the string to convert to MAT but got error by using this... Do u have any thought on this?

Comment: for(int d=0;d<256;d++)
   {
 
    testing += '0' + pixelValueArray[d];
  
    }

   cout<<testing; //this is the string
   
   cv::Mat data(1,ATTRIBUTES,CV_32F,testing.data());

Answer (score 2):

Std provides the function std::to_string() (since c++11) to convert Datatypes like int to std::string: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string .
Maybe this can help you.